# Disk o_direct on Hadoop 1.2 and Hadoop 2.7

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, redhat

Does anyone know if there is a setting for o_direct for drives in Hadoop 1.2.1 or hadoop 2.7, specifically for hadoop 1.2.1. I need it for hadoop 1.2.1 to use the kernel´s "O_DIRECT" flag.

Any information would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I found it in the xml to utilize the 0_direct kernel flag which you need to enable in the kernel from 3.x and up with.